# Is it possible to add padding to the end view in an Activity Transition?

Tags: android, android-transitions, activity-transition, shared-element-transition

I'm not sure if this is a defect or if I'm doing something wrong here. When I have an ImageView as a shared element between two activities, if the end image view has padding, the image view no longer respects the nav bar at the bottom of the screen. If I move the padding into the container view, or switch to using a margin instead, it works fine.

Video of animation with padding on second imageView: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hg4bc6h2u5o&feature=youtu.be

Video of animation without padding on second imageView: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pW4hyAfn9Hs&feature=youtu.be

First activity xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/title_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="@dimen/header_elevation"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:transitionGroup="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="@dimen/header_elevation"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

    ...
    <!-- other header layouts -->

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/header_title_cover"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/title_container"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/title_container"
    android:background="?android:colorAccent"
    android:elevation="@dimen/header_elevation"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/comic_cover"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:contentDescription="@string/placeholder_image_description"
    android:src="@drawable/dog_eat_cat"
    />
```

Second activity xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_root_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:paddingTop="80dp"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

First activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Slide ts = new Slide(Gravity.TOP);
    ts.excludeTarget(android.R.id.statusBarBackground, true)
            .excludeTarget(android.R.id.navigationBarBackground, true);
    getWindow().setReenterTransition(ts);
    getWindow().setExitTransition(ts);

    ... // set up views
}


public void openActivity() {
    imageView.setTransitionName(PagesActivity.SHARED_IMAGE_NAME);

    ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this,
            image, PagesActivity.SHARED_IMAGE_NAME);
    startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
}
```

Second Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().getEnterTransition().excludeTarget(android.R.id.statusBarBackground, true)
            .excludeTarget(android.R.id.navigationBarBackground, true);
    getWindow().getReturnTransition().excludeTarget(android.R.id.statusBarBackground, true)
            .excludeTarget(android.R.id.navigationBarBackground, true);

    ... //Load views
    imageView.setTransitionName(SHARED_IMAGE_NAME);
}
```

Comment: The problem probably doesn't have to do with the fact that it is an "end view" or whatever... it's that the image view in the first activity starts with `0dp` top padding and ends with `80dp` top padding. The shared element transition you are using to perform the animation likely doesn't know how to smoothly animate between these two values (for example, if you use `ChangeBounds` and `ChangeImageTransform`, the image will resize depending on the view's layout bounds including the padding). Is there a reason you can't use "margin top" instead?

Comment: I can work around it, but it definitely seems like a bug. Like I said, if I put the padding in a container view or use margins, it works fine. However, when I use padding, even after the view fully loads the bottom is covered by the navigation keys.

Comment: @AlexLockwood is correct. The padding is not shared between Activities. You will have to compensate. Set the padding in onSharedElementStart and then reset it in onSharedElementEnd. You'll also have to execute measure and layout on the shared view because you are modifying it.

Comment: @Gabriel did you manage to resolve this issue?

Comment: I did, I ended up changing the location of the padding to the container view and it simplified everything.

Comment: @AlexLockwood Can you please elaborate on your solution? I tried it, but cannot make it work.